# How to use Slice of Pi kit for prototyping?

Tags: gpio, hardware, wiring, breadboard

I have a [Slice of Pi](http://shop.ciseco.co.uk/slice-of-pi-add-on-for-raspberry-pi/) prototype board, but I'm somewhat confused as to how I'm supposed to use it. None of the pads in the prototype area seem to be connected. How am I supposed to wire stuff together if the pads aren't connected in the board?

(To be clear: I'm expecting this to act like a breadboard, where some pads are connected so I can solder LEDs and resistors into the holes and they'll be connected. I can tell the pads aren't connected internally because I see infinite resistance on my multimeter between the pads. Some pads are obviously wired together via traces on the board; those pads have no resistance on the multimeter.)

Edit: Based on the bottom-side image on [this](http://nathan.chantrell.net/20120602/raspberry-pi-io-expander-board/) page, one is supposed to use solder to connect adjacent pads that are to be connected. Is this correct? It seems kind of janky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should solder pads that are close enough or put small wires between pads and the pads that are already in use for the connector that goes to your pi.
Actually, the picture in your second link is pretty clear.

If you need help on how to solder your elements don't hesitate asking.
here you have [one of the funniest guides to soldering I've ever seen](http://mightyohm.com/blog/2011/04/soldering-is-easy-comic-book/)